# Swagger become root path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, rails-api, grape-api

My routes.rb is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :teachers
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

resources :student
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  resources :user
end
root 'student#index'
```

But the issue is that when I enter

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

it go swagger index.html
It doesnt work according to routes

Comment: I think it should be `root 'students#index'` not `student` ==> `students'`

Comment: what do you have when you run `rake routes`

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the list:

-> Exist file in: app/views/student/index.html
-> Exist file in: app/controllers/student_controller.rb

```
 class StudentController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end
 end
```

and try remove other routes

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a similar problem and I think it was because of the positions of the routes definitions. Try place `root 'student#index'` before `resources :students` or at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to change `resources :student` to `resources :students` because of rails conventions.

After that you can use `root 'students#index'` and remember in your students controller there must be `StudentsController` not `StudentController`. Consider plural when you defining any controller.